# How to see if a string contains multiple different letters?

Tags: c++, string, char

This is for a C++ program.
We are supposed to be able to input a word (from 4 to 10 letters in length) and then generate n scrambles of the word (n being the number of letters in the word).  Obviously, the only 2 kinds of words that cannot be scrambled under these criteria are words in which every letter is the same, and words in which every letter except for one is the same (like OOOOA). The reason for these two exceptions is that if the word is made up of the same letters then there are NO scrambles of the word because each scramble of the word is the same.  Also, the original word does not count as a scramble.  So if you have OOOOA then it generates only 4 scrambles

OOOAO
OOAOO
OAOOO
and AOOOO

when it should have 5.

For most 5 letter words (like OOAAO) there exist MANY more than 5 scrambles- but my program only needs to produce 5 of them.

Within the program I already created a function that tells me if an inputted string is made up of all of the same characters so I have the first case taken care of.  However, how should I write a function, that inputs a string, to tell me if that string can be scrambled.  In other words the function should tell me that the string

has at least three characters within it that are all different, (like QRCCC, ORJJJ, QRTEW, etc..)

or

contains a mix of characters, only two of which are the same, in which case there are at LEAST two of each different character. (like OOTTO, OTTOO, QRRQQ)

I am very new to C++ so please don't reference things that I might not understand at this point (like bubble sort.  I may know what this means but if I do I only know what it looks like in code so please don't use terminology like that unless it directly appears in code)

I have no idea what to do here.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't scramble OOOOA. What would AOOOO be then?

Comment: Well you see OOOOA is 5 letters long, and the assignment says I have to create X scrambles of the word, X being the length of the word- in this case 5.  The part I think I forgot to mention is that the original word is not a scramble.  OOOOA would result in
OOOAO
OOAOO
OAOOO
AOOOO

that's only 4.  which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: `Obviously, the only 2 kinds of words that cannot be scrambled...` Why "Obviously"?

Comment: @JesW87 Why the length of OOOAO is 4? ...makes no sense too me (too)

Comment: can you rephrase? (to deviantfan's second comment)

Comment: @Jes : As i understand for OOOOA, the scrambles could be OOOAO, OOAOO, OAOOO, AOOO. But you have mentioned in your question that OOOOA can*not* be scrambled. Could you clarify your question a bit, specifically about the _n scrambles of a word_ . A quick example showing the input and its scrambles should be good enough.

Comment: @anurag86 I'm not sure what you're asking but I'll try to explain.  My word choice there was probably confusing.  OOOOA CAN be scrambled but it cannot generate ENOUGH scrambles.  The assignment says, for instance, for a 5 letter word the program should generate 5 different scrambles of that word (not including the original word).  

If you inputted OOOOA you would only get 4 words, which is one less than I need.  If you inputted something like OOOAA you could have enough scrambles (like OAOOA, AAOOO, AOOOA, AOOAO, and AOAOO)

Comment: @JesW87: Ok. So the _number of scrambled words = lengthOfWord_ . And is it necessary to be exactly equal or the no. of scrambled words could be more than the length too? E.g. The word can have scrambles more than 4 ..... ABCD,ACBD,ADBC,ADCB,BACD,BCAD and more....

Comment: @anurag86 the number of scrambles that the program will produce is equal to the length of the word.  however, it is very possible that the number of possible scrambles that exist for that word is a LOT more than the length of the word.  Like, for a 5 letter word like OOOAA, there are a LOT more than 5 scrambles that exist- but my program only needs to produce 5 of them.  I can handle the scrambling function- I just need to make a function to identify the words that won't work.

Comment: @JesW87 one way to do it would be to make a char vector and push_back every new letter that you find, if the size of that vector exceeds 2 then stop doing it since you would be wasting time now that you know that you will find a solution. You can couple this with the first requirement easily.

Comment: Ok one- I'm new to this so I have no idea what a char vector is but for the moment I'll move past that.  If the word only contains 2 different characters like OOOAA but has At least 2 of each character (like OOOAA) then it can still scramble so how would I handle THAT situation?

Comment: @JesW87 : why reinvent the wheel when the algorithm is already provided by STL :)

Comment: @JesW87 Oh ok you could create another vector in parallel that keeps track of the number of times the corresponding letter appears, again, if both of them exceed one you break.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    cin>>word;
    int count=0;
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end()); 
    do
    {
        count++;
    }
    while (next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()));
    cout<<"Length is :"<<word.length()<<endl;
    if(count>word.length())
    {
        cout<<"No. of scrambles are >= length of word\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No. of scrambles are < length of word\n";
        return 0;
    }
    count=0;
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end()); 
    do
    {
        cout<<word<<"\n";
    }
    while (next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()));
}
```

In any case it checks for the factorial of the number of characters input by you. Repeated words wouldn't be a part of combination as you require.

Answer (score 1):

Your aim is basically to check if :

1. There are at least 3 kinds of distinct characters.
2. 2 kinds of items, each greater than or equal to 2 in number.

So you basically need to :

1. Count number of distinct characters.
2. Count number of occurrences of each character.

Follow the steps :

1. Create a string, accept the input in the string :

   ```
   string s; 
   cin>>s;
   ```
2. Create an integer vector of 26 elements(since 26 letters in English Alphabet), and initialize all to 0 :

   ```
   vector<int> count(26,0);
   ```

3.To count number of occurrences of a character, implement this code :

```
for(int i=0;i<s.size();++i)
     ++count[ s[i] - 'A' ]; //assuming all uppercase characters.
```

Now you have the number of 'A's stored in `count[0]`, number of 'B's stored in `count[1]`, and so on.

4. Declare a counter variable `distinct`, which counts the number of non-zero elements in the vector. This gives you the number of distinct characters in the string.
5. Declare a `flag` variable, and initialize it to `false`. Iterate for each element of the vector, and check whether an element of the vector has a value 1 or not. If you encounter a 1 in the vector, make `flag = true;`.

You have almost reached the answer. You just need to check the the following conditions to tell whether the word can be scrambled or not :

```
bool can_be_scrambled = true;
if(distinct == 1 || (distinct == 2 && flag == true) )
    can_be_scrambled = false;
```

Comment: Took me a little to go through all 5 steps. Nice :)

Comment: Yeah thanks! I didn't know about the next_permutation function used in your answer, it seems good. But I guess it won't be as efficient as this one, right, since you mentioned it will run (n!) times, n being size of string.

Comment: I guess not even though im not sure of the internal implementation of next_permutation but AFAIK  STL algo's are supposed to be most optimised and efficient. I ran _do while_ twice , once just to see if the no. of scrambled words are more than the length and second time for priinting it actually. It could have contained a check in the first loop to run only _word.length_ times to make it litle more efficient.

Comment: Yes, but the time complexity won't go below O(n!).

Comment: For _ANY_ algorithm, the Big O(not Omega) would always be O(n!).